# PHPDocumentor - Graphviz 'dot' command not found

Tags: graphviz, phpdoc

I am trying to get PHPDocumentor running on a local XAMPP installation.
Sadly I having a hard time doing it using package managers. 
Some basic questions about package managers first:

1. How do I know where to install a package? For example: I installed  PHPDocumentor using Composer. I go to my C:\xampp\htdocs\ and run a command:

   > composer require "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor:2.*"

This installs phpdocumentor in a " vendor" folder in xampp\htdocs\

- Is this the correct path to install all these packages or is there a default dir to install this?
- If I want to uninstall the packages, do I simply delete the "vendor" dir?

  2. After the installation I ran PHPdocumentor and got an error:

> Unable to find the `dot` command of the GraphViz package. Is GraphViz
>   correctly installed and present in your path?

To resolve this, I tried the following:

Installed the package graph/graphviz while my pointer was in the htdocs-folder and pointed a path to the folders:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\graph\graphviz
...graph\graphviz\src
...graph\graphviz\tests
```

None of the above solved the problem.
According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28194072/dont-get-graphviz-and-phpdocumentor-to-work) I have to add the \graphiz\bin directory to path, but there is no "bin" dir?

Can anyone help me out with this?

Best regards,
Abayob

Comment: I solved the 'dot' command problem by installing a full Graphviz-installation of 184MB on my drive (downloaded installer from Graphviz download page). With this installation a bin-dir was installed, so I added this dir to the PATH.
After this, I can run the phpdoc run without errors.

I seriously think there has to be another way? 
I don't like to have 184MB of usefull stuff on my PC just to run the 'dot' command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Unable to find the dot command of the GraphViz package. Is GraphViz correctly installed and present in your path?

The steps to resolve this error are:

1. download zip from https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html
2. extract to `c:\some\where\graphviz`
3. add `c:\some\where\graphviz\bin` to your environment variable `PATH`
4. run phpdoc

> I don't like to have 184MB of usefull stuff on my PC just to run the 'dot' command?

Yes, its a lot of stuff. A more lightweight solution would be nice.

Comment: What do u mean "environment path"?

Comment: I mean the environment variable `PATH`. You can show the content with `echo %PATH%`. Add the path to graphviz there to make it executable from everywhere...